# Identifying 1970s-80s Motobecane Special Sport

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage, french

I'm trying to identify the exact year/model of a Motobecane called the "Special Sport", which was bought in France. I don't know if the parts are all original, however: It has a [Huret Svelto](http://www.disraeligears.co.uk/Site/Huret_Svelto_derailleur_1st_style.html) rear derailleur, but I can't tell what model the Huret front derailleur is. It has Motobecane-branded center-pull brakes. Lastly, it has a [Maillard Helicomatic](http://www.borgercompagnie.com/helicomatic/history.html) rear hub, which would suggest to me that it's an early-'80s model, but the rest of the bike doesn't look very '80s at all.

[image: Side]

[image: Front]

[image: Chainring]

[image: Rear derailleur]

[image: Rear axle]

Comment: It's very confusing to post so many different well-lit, in-focus pictures of different parts of the bike. Couldn't you instead post a dark, grainy photo of half a generic BMX that's had most of its components replaced? Thanks! ;-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm sure if I had some hustle, I could make a career out of making really nice photos of old bikes in different locales just before I have to sell them because I have to move and can't afford to bring them along.

Comment: 5 rear cogs, Mafac-type brakes, cottered steel cranks, the plastic-metal front lamp, steel mudguards are indicative of early 70s rather than 80s. A standard French built bike from around 1970. I got a similar Peugeot as a teenager in those days..

Comment: @Carel I'm envious: My first bike was a cheap BMX. If I had got one of these as a kid, I would probably have kept biking through my teenage years.

Answer (score 3):

The frame is a 70-73 motobecane. This head badge was used during this year.
 in 74 it was changed to the round version
[image]
I however dont see a frame in their catalogs called a super sport, so not to sure about that. however you seem to have matching components to the Grand Touring from this time period.
Here are some old [catalog scans](http://bulgier.net/pics/bike/catalogs/Motobecane/)

Comment: Yes, you're right: It turns out it's called a ["Special Sport"](https://www.2ememain.be/v%C3%A9los/v%C3%A9los/v%C3%A9los-de-course/2-randonneuse-motobecane-special-sport-371409954.html): I can't handle all of these "super" "special" "sporty" names.

Comment: I would think it is the Gran Touring model, just got some "upgrades" at some point in  the 80s, with the light, and new wheels.

Comment: Might it be possible, then, that the Gran Touring was sold as "Special Sport" in some weird manner, e.g. as a regional speciality in France/Belgium or as an alternate marque (a la Ford vs. Mercury)?

Comment: let it be said that this was just their basic catalog. it is completely possible that the super sport came with fenders and a rack and whatever else, accessory wise, however the grand touring was the base model it was built off of. Same way bike companies do it today.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Motobecane Spécial Sport and believe it must date back to somewhere between 70 - 73. I've seen a couple more of them here & there on the web but none of them in catalogue scans!

Comment: Thank you for joining the site and providing your first answer.  Feel free to come back and used Edit to expand the answer as you recall other relevant points.  Also, do please have a read of our [tour] to see how things work.

Comment: Are you saying that _all_ Motobecane Special Sports date to that era? It's not very clear from your answer and, if you're just saying that your bike is from the early 1970s, how does that help the asker?